# Извлечь координаты метки из расширения и сохранить в БД

Tags: javascript, yii, yandex-maps-api

Использую расширение для работы с яндекс картой в Yii и проблема в следующем:
Как по клике на кнопку

```
 <div class="modal-footer">
        <?php
            $this->widget('bootstrap.widgets.TbButton', array(
                'buttonType'=>'submit',
                'label'=>'Подтвердить',
                'type'=>'primary',
            ));
        ?>
```

сохранить в БД координаты метки? Как через ajax обратиться к getPosition(), если эта функция находится в .js файле в папке assets используемого расширения.